# Is there 3D printed PLA propellers efficiency comparison?

Tags: propellers

I have seen many tests about the resistance of PLA 3D printed propellers, and they are very strong and able to withstand a considerable high RPM level, not really a surprise considering that the weak point of PLA in mechanical properties is poor impact resistance but out of this, it is way harder and stiffer than ABS.

Unfortunately, I haven't found a valid comparative test of their efficiency.

Considering that PLA has higher specific weight and with 3D print the surface cannot be as smooth as the one obtained with molding manufacture, I would expect a lower efficiency but I have no idea about **the amount** of this loss.

Quantify the loss of efficiency of PLA FDM propeller manufacturing would be very helpful also to have more valid data when try to experiment with prototyping of new propeller designs.

Does anyone have reliable data about this topic?